# What is the point of explaining how a magnet works in Opposite House?

Tags: meaning

In the song, Opposite House by Cass McComb what is the point of explaining how a magnet works?

> How do you make a magnet?
>   You create a potential
>   Just an old refrigerator magnet
>   Repelled and pulled
>   Ooohhhh why so needy?
>   Tell me why

And maybe I'm missing the meaning of the song.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR6l9UOpM2w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lyrics are an oblique look at a relationship, and **every line is a metaphor for a situation within that relationship**.

When he says "How do you make a magnet? You create a potential," the question he's really trying to answer is **"how do I attract [this person] back to me?"**  *[Magnetic potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential)* is a technical term used in electromagnetics, but in this case, the potential he's considering is whether the relationship can "potentially" be revived.

**Alternately, you can read this as saying that *he's* the magnet**, alternately pulled and repelled, and that he was created as one by the potential of a relationship being dangled in front of him (which perhaps fits better in context --it seems more likely he's criticizing himself as being a "needy" magnet than his lover).

Either way, the key line to understanding this song comes a stanza or so earlier:

> One step forward two steps back
>   They say **opposites attract**
>   But they haven't tracked
>   In my heart shack

This is the connector between the title narrative of the "opposite house", and the specific metaphor of the magnets.